# I am getting incorrect value on X- axis of scatterplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, scatter-plot, numpy-ndarray

My scatter plot looks like this:

The following is the command is used to plot the scatter plot:

```
 plt.scatter(x,y[:,0],c="c", alpha=0.3)
```

Here, both x and y are numpy arrays. The values look like:

```
 x:
       array([  36259516,   36259544,   36259600, ..., 9251680654, 
        9251680675, 9296284549], dtype=int64)      

 y:
      array([[ 0.91122632],
      [ 0.79788549],
      [ 0.87083686],
       ..., 
      [ 0.77459159],
      [ 0.69324043],
      [ 0.77459159]])
```

Note: In short, I wanna plot all the values 'y' values of unique 'x'.

[image]

If you could see, even if passing different array on x-axis , when the graph is plotted , I could notice both axis representing y-axis values.

Can anyone help me solve this issue.

Comment: Did you notice the `1e10` multiplier at the bottom right?

Comment: Yes. I don't know what it means. And could you help why we are getting the same values on both axis

Comment: Your highest X value is 9296284549, which is 0.9296e10.  The values on the X-axis are to be multiplied by the 1e10 at the lower right.